Is duckdb table persisted
I have a huge parquet file. I only want to explore a specific sunset of it. That is hundreds of rows out a hundred of million rows.
So I do this to create a temporary table vloc1
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE vloc1 AS FROM '.data/muni_vloc_202101.parquet' WHERE vid=5773

Like many things with duckdb, it works great. Querying the vloc1 table is instantaneous.
My question is, where does vloc1 exists? Is it in memory? On disk? Should I drop the table when I'm done? I am doing all this in a Python session in Jupyter notebook.

it only exists in memory and needs persisting if you want to keep it. however,share your actual code to be sur.
